# Android Java - change requestLocationUpdates refresh in class

Tags: java, android, class, gps

I have this class GPS_Service below. It's working perfectly. From MainActivity I  can change the value of variable GPS_Service.gpsupdatedelay to adjust how often the GPS is invoked via requestLocationUpdates in GPS_Service. From MainActivity I change the value via GPS_Service.gpsupdatedelay = 10000; I think I also need to invoke some aspect of GPS_Service to make the variable value change take place? I cannot see a way to invoke GPS_Service.onCreate() nor do I think I should do that?

QUESTION: After having adjusted the value of gpsupdatedelay, how may I get the variable value-change in the parameters of requestLocationUpdates to take place and actually adjust the GPS frequency?

Thank you in advance.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPS_Service extends Service {
    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    public static Integer gpsupdatedelay;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e("GPS","onCreate");
        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                //i.putExtra("coordinates",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLatitude());

                i.putExtra("coordinate1",location.getLatitude());
                i.putExtra("coordinate2",location.getLongitude());
                Log.e("GPS","sendBroadcast");
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,gpsupdatedelay,0,listener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(locationManager != null){
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually should not have the `gpsupdatedelay` variable defined as static.  Instead of having it defined as static and accessing it directly from the Activity, send in the new value as an Intent Extra when you need to update it.

The first step is to define the `onStartCommand()` method override, which will update the new interval value, unregister the old location listener, and re-register for location updates with the new interval:

```
public class GPS_Service extends Service {
    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    public Integer gpsupdatedelay = 10000; //NOT static!

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    //Added:
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int newGpsUpdateDelay = intent.getIntExtra("new_gps_update_delay", -99);
        if (newGpsUpdateDelay != -99 && locationManager != null) {
            gpsupdatedelay = newGpsUpdateDelay;
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,gpsupdatedelay,0,listener);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e("GPS","onCreate");
        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                //i.putExtra("coordinates",location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLatitude());

                i.putExtra("coordinate1",location.getLatitude());
                i.putExtra("coordinate2",location.getLongitude());
                Log.e("GPS","sendBroadcast");
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,gpsupdatedelay,0,listener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(locationManager != null){
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to update the value from the Activity, just create an Intent, put the new value in the `new_gps_update_delay` Extra, and call `startService()` in order to send the updated info to the Service:

```
    int newDelay = 678;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GPS_Service.class);
    i.putExtra("new_gps_update_delay", newDelay);
    startService(i);
```

This works since the `startService()` method can be called even if the Service is already running.  If the service is already running, essentially it just runs the `onStartCommand()` method override.

From [the documentation for startService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)):

> If this service is not already running, it will be instantiated and
>   started (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then
>   it remains running.
>
> Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the
>   target service's `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` method, with the
>   intent given here. This provides a convenient way to submit jobs to a
>   service without having to bind and call on to its interface.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I appreciate it. Quick question with your code above to update the variable. The location service is starting today. So, will using startService(i) cause the location service to be started again and duplicated, or will startService(i) causing the existing/running location service to be stopped/restarted or does  startServuce(i) just pass the variable in and not effect the running of the location service at all? You can likely tell, I am new to Android/Java.

Comment: Thanks again - After updating the class with the recommended changes, and adjust the invocation of the class from MainActivity I received this error: "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.ftonyan.gps4, PID: 15469
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.ftonyan.gps6.GPS_Service: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3158)"

Comment: I appreciate the help, just wondering what I did incorrectly.

Comment: @FrankZappa It looks like maybe you don't have an initial value anymore. Take a look at the edit I just made: `public Integer gpsupdatedelay = 10000;`

Comment: Daniel - thanks. You were right. It was being started with no initial delay value. Now it compiles and runs. I am testing to determine if it will adjust the delay based on the programmed events. Thanks very much for your help.